# Access to XMLHttpRequest at"url" from origin has blocked by CORS policy: No'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, export-to-excel

While returning an excel file from API for an angular project(Export to Excel), I got this error in my angular application. how to solve this issue.

In Api Side method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost("ExportToExcel")]
 public async Task<IActionResult>ExportToExcelAsync(InputModelDTO inputModelDTO )
        {
       
           
            var ReportDetails = await 
            _Service.ExportToExcelAsync(inputModelDTO );
          
            var content = excelFile.ToArray();
            Response.Headers.Add("x-file-name", "" + actualFile + ".xlsx");
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "" + actualFile + ".xlsx");
            return File(
            content,
           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
           "" + actualFile + ".xlsx");
        }
```

I also implement a core's policy in my web API startUp class, code is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
               services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
         }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){   
           app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
        }
```

I also give this attribute in my controller like:

```
 [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```

Comment: Where you put `app.UseCors("MyPolicy");`.It needs to be put between `app.UseRouting();` and ` app.UseAuthorization();`.You can refer to [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).

Comment: I already put  a app.UseCors("MyPolicy");  between app.UseRouting(); and app.UseAuthorization();.I cant understand what is the actual problem.